# How to get Socket IP address behind NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: sockets, nginx, proxy, socket.io

I am using Socket.io to create a chat application. My server sits behind an Nginx reverse proxy. How should i get the IP addresses of the clients that connect to my chat application.

```
 console.log(socket.request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.request.connection.remoteAddress);
```

Using this gives me the IP address of the reverse proxy server. Someone please help??

Comment: You should configure your nginx to send `X-Forwarder-For` header

Comment: @AnubhavMishra Can you plz tell how you configured the nginx for those headers? I am running into same issue right now